# Why ArcGIS JavaScript text label does not show on feature?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-class, feature-layer, feature-collection

[My working example](https://codepen.io/boliwe/pen/KKMPmqb) here does not show the labeling information on features.

```
    var featureLayer;

    map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "satellite",
      center: [-46.807, 32.553],
      zoom: 3
    });


    //create a feature collection for the flickr photos
    var featureCollection = {
      "layerDefinition": null,
      "featureSet": {
        "features": [               
            new Graphic({ 
                geometry: new Point(-47.476661, 42.702002, map.spatialReference),
                attributes: {ObjectID:1 ,title: "my title", description: "my description"}  
            }),
            new Graphic({ 
                geometry: new Point(-46.476661, 31.702002, map.spatialReference),
                attributes: {ObjectID:2 ,title: "my title", description: "my description"}  
            })
        ],
        "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint"
      }
    };
    featureCollection.layerDefinition = {
      "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
      "objectIdField": "ObjectID",
      "drawingInfo": {
        "renderer": {
          "type": "simple",
          "symbol": {
            "type": "esriSMS",
             "style": "esriSMSCircle",
             "color": [216, 15, 20, 255],
             "size": 18,
            }
        }
      },
      "fields": [{
        "name": "ObjectID",
        "alias": "ObjectID",
        "type": "esriFieldTypeOID"
      }, {
        "name": "description",
        "alias": "Description",
        "type": "esriFieldTypeString"
      }, {
        "name": "title",
        "alias": "Title",
        "type": "esriFieldTypeString"
      }]
    };


    featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection, {
      id: 'my-layer'
    });
    
    var labelClass = new LabelClass({
        "labelExpressionInfo": {"value": "{title} title"},
        "labelPlacement":"above-right",
        "symbol": new TextSymbol()
    });
    
    featureLayer.setLabelingInfo([ labelClass ])
    
    
    map.addLayers([featureLayer]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indicate the map to show the labels. In order to do this just set `Map` property `showLabels` to `true`. In your code,

```
map = new Map("map", {
  basemap: "satellite",
  center: [-46.807, 32.553],
  zoom: 3,
  showLabels: true // <- HERE
});
```